# MySql delete where find_in_set not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a MySql stored procedure that has multiple parts. Procedure receives an INT "inId" and a VARCHAR(500) argument called "inIgnoreLogTypes" that's a comma-separated list of numbers.

First part of SQL looks like this:

```
DECLARE affectedNumbers text;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(am.Numbers) INTO affectedNumbers FROM Users am WHERE am.userID = inId;
```

I need to do that because variable "affectedNumbers" will be used later on throughout this rather big stored procedure so for sake of performances i don't wanna do "IN (Select ...)" every time i need to look up the list.

I checked, variable "affectedNumbers" get's correctly populated with comma separated values.
Next part is this (and that's where the problem occurs):

```
DELETE FROM UserLogs WHERE
FIND_IN_SET(User_Number, affectedNumbers) AND
NOT FIND_IN_SET(LogType, inIgnoreLogTypes);
```

Above statement does nothing and after hours of searching for "why" i can't find the answer... Maybe because "affcetedNumbers" is TEXT and "User_Number" is INT? Or maybe because "LogType" is INT and "inIgnoreLogTypes" is VARCHAR?

I checked both sets, they are comma separated integers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue! I have to use something like this:

```
DELETE FROM UserLogs WHERE
FIND_IN_SET(UserLogs.User_Number, affectedNumbers) AND
NOT FIND_IN_SET(UserLogs.LogType, inIgnoreLogTypes);
```

Strange, as there were no errors.... Now it works.